# How can I find out if a cell in Excel contains a number/text or a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

What I like to do is conditionally format cells depending on whether the cell contains a formula (something starting with "=") or not.

Is this feasible in Excel 2007?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
If (cell.HasFormula) then ..
```

To look for formulas.

(This will avoid the problem of literal string field starting with an "=")

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was trying to avoid VBA. But it seems not possible. Googling HasFormula brought up a second option I sketch below.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no readily accessible worksheet function or conditional to test for formulae.  VBA offers the `range.HasFormula` method that returns true if every cell in the range (which can be a single cell) has a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference (and for upvoting :-)), I finally solved the automatic coloring with VBA, without using conditional formatting:

```
dim ws as Worksheet
for each ws in thisworkbook.sheets
  ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
next ws
```

works fine for me. (Found [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2006/12/excel-vba-how-to-know-if-cell-has.html))

Comment: That's a nice trick.  I was hoping to color the entire row if a particular column had a formula in it.  That doesn't seem possible without VBA, but this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this has been inactive for over a year but given the repeated comments about hoping to avoid VBA I though it was worth posting the XLM with Range Names approach.

drawing on David Hager's code from http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/eee/eee003.txt

1. Define a range name IsFormula   refers to:=GET.CELL(48,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))
2. Add a Conditional Formatting rule "using a formula to determine which cells to format" = IsFormula to the range of interest and pick your colour

And you are done

The historical advantage of using XLM was that it allowed VBA like coding without providing macro warnings. The presence of XLM now flags a similar content warning but it is still useful to be able to apply these conditional formatting XLM tricks without having to trigger a VBA event in the background.

I have written a longer article on using XLM/ Range Names/Conditional Formmating to indentify external cell links, sheet links, formulae etc and inconsistent formulae at http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_7629.html *(please note that this lies outside the EE paywall, it is freely accessible without membership)*